# Width in a img balise inside a div or any other parent element

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox, display

I need the help of the community.

I have 3 elements inside a header parent element like below :

```html
<header class="flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
  <div>
    <img src="Assets/images/logo_white.png">
  </div>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href=""></a>Roadmap</li>
    <li>
      <a href=""></a>Artist</li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
    <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
  </ul>
  <button>
            <a href="">Lorem </a>
        </button>
</header>
```

I add a display flex to align the three-element and then a space-between. And my problem is that the IMG inside the div element takes much more width than the others but without the div, everything works just fine.

This is the only css I have :

```scss
.flex {
  padding: 1.25rem 3.125rem 1.25rem 3.125rem;
  border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  font-family: 'Outfit';
  display: flex;
  &-jc-sb {
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  &-ai-c {
    align-items: center;
  }
  img {
    width: 5%;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
  }
  ul {
    li {
      display: inline;
      color: white;
      i {
        color: white;
      }
    }
  }
```

**With the Img balise inside a div**
[image: With the Img balise inside a div]

**with the Img balise alone**
[image]

I hope I am clear enough.

Thank you guys for your help.

Comment: Never use action elements inside other action elements `BUTTON>A` or `A>BUTTON` is invalid markup.

Comment: you can try to add max-width

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan did not see that semantic issue my first time through. edited.

Comment: Thanks @RokoC.Buljan but how then can you add a href for the button ?

Comment: And how can have a title close to the image ? I mean because of the flexbox the title is width away from the image.

Comment: Simply don't use a Button if you need an Anchor. Use Anchors to navigate and Buttons to perform non-navigation actions (like i.e. submit a form, toggle a menu, open a modal, etc...). Your question is unclear, what is the desired end result? Where should be the text? centered? Why to you use that DIV at all?

Comment: When the image is inside the DIV there is a large width look in the first image. When the image is not inside a div there is no large width. I need to understand why I have this kind of behaviour.

Comment: @MohamedNecib Not quite sure what you mean by large width. Are you talking about a large gap? Please consider letting me know what my answer is lacking compared to your desired end-result.

Comment: I think by just looking at the image you will understand it properly. And a width is a width and a gap is a gap. I'm using the right word.

Comment: @MohamedNecib did my answer guide you at all?

Answer (score 0):

Here is one version using pure CSS. Instead of nesting the image in the div, you should nest the `ul` and `a` in the div. Where you can then set a display `flex` with a `gap`. Then I would flex the parent `header` and use `space-between`.

**EDIT** ~ Should never use an `a` tag with a `button`. I would advise using an `a` for links and `buttons` for actions. You can use `role="button"` on an a tag.

```css
.flex {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: flex;
  gap: 2px;
}

header>img~div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

a.btn {
  background-color: #e1e1e1;
  padding: 3px;
  outline: solid 1px;
  color: black;
  text-decoration: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
}
```

```html
<header class="flex flex-jc-sb flex-ai-c">
  <img src="Assets/images/logo_white.png">
  <div>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>Roadmap</li>
      <li>
        <a href=""></a>Artist</li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
      <li><a href=""><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
        <a href="#" class="btn" role="button">Lorem</a>
  </div>

</header>
```